# Access a character in a string that has more than 2^31 characters

Tags: java, string, char, stringbuilder, biginteger

I've been trying to access a characters from a string that has a 1 Trillion characters. I am using BigInteger for getting the index number from a string and charAt method to access a character from the String.

What I'm trying to do is to count the occurrence of a specific character in a String given.

For example, String: `aaaaaaa`...*up to 1 trillion characters of 'a'*. Then I will count the occurrence of character 'a' (the given character to count)

How can I access the characters from a string that has more than 2,147,483,647 (2^31)? Is there any other way on doing this?

### Snippet of code:

```
BigInteger String_Length = BigInteger.valueOf(n); //1,000,000,000,000
    BigInteger Occurence = BigInteger.valueOf(0);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char c; 

    for(BigInteger First_Counter = BigInteger.valueOf(0); First_Counter.compareTo(String_Length) <= 0; First_Counter = First_Counter.add(BigInteger.ONE)){
        for(BigInteger Char_Counter = BigInteger.valueOf(0); Char_Counter.compareTo(String_Length) <= 0; Char_Counter = Char_Counter.add(BigInteger.ONE)){
            c = s.charAt(Char_Counter);
            c = sb.append(c);
        }
    }

    for(BigInteger Second_Counter = BigInteger.valueOf(0); Second_Counter.compareTo(String_Length) <= 0; Second_Counter = Second_Counter.add(BigInteger.ONE)){
        c = sb.charAt(Second_Counter); 

        if(c == 'a')
            Occurence = Occurence.add(BigInteger.ONE);

    }
```

### Errors

> 1. error: no suitable method found for charAt(BigInteger)
>                  c = s.charAt(Char_Counter);
> 2. method CharSequence.charAt(int) is not applicable
>        (argument mismatch; BigInteger cannot be converted to int)
> 3. error: incompatible types: StringBuilder cannot be converted to char
>                  c = sb.append(c);

Comment: A string cannot have more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` characters.

Comment: What is unclear in the error message? charAt() expects an int. You're passing a BigInteger. A BigInteger is not an int. So that can't possibly compile. As simple as that.

Comment: @JBNizet is there another way or method that can handle BigInteger ?

Comment: And you need to do some basic math when dealing with such problems. 1 trillion characters, even assuming the string uses just one byte per character, would need 1000 GB of RAM. Do you have that?

Comment: As previously stated, Strings in java cannot be longer than Integer.MAX_VALUE (and their length is also limited by the maximum heap size you can attain, divided by 2).

Comment: I'm just going to throw this out there: why do you have a two-billion character string in the first place?

Comment: @JoeC maybe he's dealing with human genome :) A human genome has over 6 billion bases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.String` is not an appropriate for very large strings. `BigInteger` would not be an appropriate type to index strings larger than 2^31 - use `long`.

Construction of a string requires the data already in memory, so two copies. Further buffers will typically be resized prior to construction, which requires at least twice the actual data size plus any extra capacity in the buffer.

Further the internal storage of `String` characters (typically `char` but others are available) may not be appropriate for your data. Also, do you want to be creating a `BigInteger` object together with internal array to access each index.

Even `java.nio` uses `int` to index its buffers (currently).

So you'll want to write your own `BigString` indexed by `long`, backed by an array of arrays. Or more likely an array (or `List`) of memory mapped NIO buffers.

Comment: Alternatively, the OP could read the data using a `Reader` or `InputStream` without ever needing to have everything in memory.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I’m assuming the OP had a good reason for having it all in memory at once.

Comment: I'd sooner guess that the OP hadn't considered how much memory is needed to keep a string of longer than 2^31-1 in memory.

Comment: I dealt with bugs arising from 2 GB arrays seven or eight years ago. Moore's Law would suggest we should see common uses of such things by now. And it's a more interesting question to answer.